# Why this syntax for renaming columns in datasets?

Tags: syntax, dataset

Form the documentation of Dataset:

```
    dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

gives a Dataset with columns "a", "b" and "c". To rename a column in a Dataset one uses the syntax

```
 dataset[All,<|"New"->"old"|>]
```

where "old" is the old column name and "New" is the new one. Here (also from the documentation):

```
dataset[All, <|"A" -> "a", "B" -> "b", "C" -> "c"|>]
```

and one gets the new Dataset with columns "A", "B" and "C". I wonder why this is in this way and not:

```
 dataset[All,<|"old"->"New"|>]
```

Can one give me a hint?

Comment: The `"old"` is implicitly `#["old"]`. With that in mind, `#["old"]->"New"` is not what we want;  `"New"->#["old"]`  is.

Answer (score 7):

Just came across the same problem and find the following might be a sensible way:

```
dataset[All,KeyMap[Replace["old" -> "New"]]]
```

This approach essentially conducts the idea of OP and reserves the names of other columns.

BTW, I find [the way suggested by the official documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) to rename columns (i.e., using `Association` as the operator) seems a bit tedious as unconnected columns are also involved to construct a new `Association`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to think about the short-hand query syntax is to turn to the documentation of `Query`, where we find that `Query[All,f]` will apply the function `f` to every row.  So `Query[All, <|"aaa" -> #"a"|> &]` would be the natural way to write a query.  The way you wrote it (i.e., `Query[All, <|"aaa" -> "a"|> ]`) is allowed as a more compact expression of the same query.

(Btw, this is not really "renaming", since it produces a new dataset.)

Comment: But... I do not see how this answers the main question: why `"New"->"old"` instead of `"old"->"New"`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Again, the reason is that you are effectively using a shorthand for a function definition, where this kind of function allows you to extract values from an association by using the keys.  Again, this is really *not* renaming: it is effectively creating a new dataset by mapping this function across the rows of the old dataset.  Try it that way to see: `<|"aaa" -> #"a"|> & /@ dataset`.  You can use any function you want to, of course, but try to think of one that would use the notation you suggest...

Comment: Thanks, now I got it!